# Triangle texture mapping OpenGL

Tags: opengl, mapping, textures

I am working on a project using the Marching Cubes algorithm and changing the data into a 3D model. Now I want to use texture mapping in OpenGL for my 3D model. I have tried a simple example to begin with, which maps a picture onto a triangle.

Here is my code:

```
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)    // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();                            // Reset The Current Matrix
    glTranslatef(1.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);               // Move Into The Screen 5 Units
    glRotatef(xrot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);              // Rotate On The X Axis
    glRotatef(yrot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);              // Rotate On The Y Axis
    glRotatef(zrot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);              // Rotate On The Z Axis
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);    // Select Our Texture
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -2,  0, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  2,  0, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(0.5, 1); glVertex3f(  0,  2, -2 );

    glEnd();

    xrot+=0.3f;                             // X Axis Rotation
    yrot+=0.2f;                             // Y Axis Rotation
    zrot+=0.4f;                             // Z Axis Rotation
    return true;                            // Keep Going
}
```

Now the problem is that the picture does not map completely within the triangle, and the program cut the image for the triangle, so I am losing some part of my data.
How can I  map the whole image into the triangle?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. You have created a triangle with texture coordinates. The texture itself is a rectangle. So you're more or less cutting a triangular shape out of your texture. What is the problem? What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you could illustrate?

Comment: Continuing what @Bart said, you can not have all of a rectangular texture mapped to a triangle without having major distortions or significant untextured space. Just add one more texture coordinate and one new vertex and you will be able to draw the whole texture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to load the entire texture as a rectangle/square, you have to make a square in OpenGL using either a quad or two triangles, and then map half of the texture to each triangle.

Like this:

```
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)    // Here's Where We Do All The Drawing
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();                            // Reset The Current Matrix
    glTranslatef(1.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);               // Move Into The Screen 5 Units
    glRotatef(xrot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);              // Rotate On The X Axis
    glRotatef(yrot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);              // Rotate On The Y Axis
    glRotatef(zrot,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);              // Rotate On The Z Axis
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);    // Select Our Texture
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    // first triangle, bottom left half
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f( -2,  0, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  2,  0, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -2,  2, -2 );

    // second triangle, top right half
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(  2,  0, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f( -2,  2, -2 );
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(  2,  2, -2 );

    glEnd();

    xrot+=0.3f;                             // X Axis Rotation
    yrot+=0.2f;                             // Y Axis Rotation
    zrot+=0.4f;                             // Z Axis Rotation
    return true;                            // Keep Going
}
```